# How to get contract deployer address using ethers.js?

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, contract

I wanna know the way to get contract deployer address after contract deployed.

```
let contract = await factory.deploy
 (name, name + "NFT");
 await contract.deployed();
 let deployer = contract.deployTransaction.from;
```

I can get deployer using deploy contract.
But I need to get in backend.
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example:

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

  async function main() {
    const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Contract");
    const contract = await Contract.deploy();
    await contract.deployed();
    
    console.log("Contract deployed to: ", contract.address);    
    
    }
    
  main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't it get the deployed contract address, but not the address of the deployer ?